# org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException when running Selenium from command prompt

Tags: java, batch-file, selenium, firefox, command-prompt

To be perfectly clear, Firefox WILL RUN just fine if I right click and run my XML files from within Eclipse.  HOWEVER, If I try to run the exact same files from a .bat file that changes directory, I am getting the following error:

```
Starting test in FireFox
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
efox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1469730154261   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.2
1469730154262   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1469730154263   addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.3.2
1469730154277   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1469730154278   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1469730154278   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1469730154278   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1469730154278   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1469730154278   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1469730154283   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1469730154283   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1469730154283   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1469730154284   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1469730154284   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1469730154284   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1469730155755   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1469730155760   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1469730155760   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1469730155761   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
JavaScript warning: resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/system/environment.js, line 15: Proxy.create and Proxy.createFunction are deprecated, use new Proxy instead
1469730156204   addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1469730156205   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
1469730156207   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
1469730156221   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1469730156221   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1469730156222   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1469730156224   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1469730156224   addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1469730156267   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
1469730156301   DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded
console.error: all-aboard-v1:
  Either no config.json file was created, or it was placed at the wrong location. Error:
  Message: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIChannel.open2]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modul
```

Here is the bat file I am using:

```
set TEST=map_test.xml
cd C:\selenium\project
java -cp C:\selenium\project\lib\*;C:\selenium\project\bin org.testng.TestNG %TEST%
set /p=Hit ENTER to continue...
```

I know the bat file is good because everything works just fine in Chrome.  I know my Firefox version and Selenium are good because they both work in Eclipse no problem.  Its just trying to access Firefox from the command line that the issue is here.  I have double checked my libraries and everything looks in order.

The only thing I can think of is ChromeDriver has no issue here because it's explicitly defined location in the system property where as firefox is just defaultly defined in Selenium.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I was running Firefox 47.0.1 with Selenium 2.52.0.  This works in the Eclipse IDE but for some reason not from a command prompt or .bat file.  The only thing I changed was to downgrade Firefox to 46.0.1.  I even tried 47.0.1 32 bit and 64 bit but no go.  Downgrading was the solution for this one.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox driver is included in the selenium-server-stanalone.jar file. I guess this jar is not part of C:\selenium\project\lib\ folder.

Please download the compatible one and try running it.

Hope this may help...

Comment: You were right about the server jar not being in the lib folder but it didnt help.  I am still getting no connection for Firefox.  It knows to open the browser window but its blank for a while then closes and fails the test same as before.

Comment: What is your firefox version? and What selenium serverjar you are using?

Comment: Firefox is 47.0.1 and the serverjar is 2.53.1.  It makes no sense to me that firefox will run fine directly from eclipse but even a bat file in the same directory as my xmls it will not.